# How to integrate the accordion jquery UI in HTML/blade in Laravel 4?

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-4, laravel-blade

**GOAL**

I've been trying to integrate the accordion jquery UI on my page, but I couldn't get it to work.

I linked all the required CDN

I am using HTML/blade.

---

I've tried this

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    // Text inside the accordion
    </p>
  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>


@stop
```

---

**Detail Photo**

[image]

---

Can someone help me point out what I missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

You have imported the jQuery-UI `.js` files and stylesheet by `//code.jquery.com-blah blah/`

I guess the right way to do it is `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js` you are missing the `http`. Or download the js file and the css file to your local and import it.

And Last, the accordion works with more than 1 block of code. So if you add one more block of `<h3>` and `<div>`, it'll work fine.

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/Ljj0afm2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```